# Disappearing feeds in IE

Tags: internet-explorer-8, rss, feed

Yesterday I had my feed list in IE8.
Now I have none.

I didn't do any 'cleaning' of my system in the last 24 hours.

Does anyone have an idea of why the feeds would have gone away, causing me to have to re-subscribe to them all?

**Edit:**  Well after having it happen a second time, I gave up and tried Newsgator.  Then all my subscriptions dissapeared from it, so now I'm trying Google Reader.  I'll leave this question up in case someone figures it out sometime.

Answer (score 1):

Your Anti Virus might be mistaking it for malware.

Comment: Hmmm, that's an interesting thought, but since I'm not in control of the anti-virus software, I wouldn't be able to fix that.  Thanks for the input.